# MK802 - Android 4.0 Mini PC - not listed with 'adb devices' command - how to install my app

Tags: android

I recently purchased the MK802; Android 4.0 Mini PC.  However, I am unable to install the apps I developed.  I have tried using the 'adb devices' command but the device does not appear on the list.  I have also downloaded the Andorid 4.0 SDK (the version used in th MK802) on my computer but still no luck.  I also made sure to enable 'USB Debugging' and 'Unknown Sources' in the device settings.

I realize I can load my app from an SD card (but I would have to buy one); or that I can download my app onto the device by making it available on a server or the android marketplace but these options seem like too much effort just to install an app.

Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Another simple alternative is to email yourself the apk and open the email from the MK802 to install the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply adb over USB **doesn't work** (for now)
The only thing that you can do is: USE WIRELESS ADB!
[This widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ryosoftware.adbw&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5yeW9zb2Z0d2FyZS5hZGJ3Il0.) can help you on enabling it.
Once you got everything up and running do an

```
adb connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

using as IP the ip address of the MK802. Once connected run an

```
adb shell
```

as usual to access the remote shell. Still the system is in heavy development (at least allwinner told so)

---

**EDIT**: Using a shorter USB cable could solve the issue!

Comment: I found what's the problem: the USB cable is a LOW QUALITY USB CABLE!!!Use a shorter one like this
http://img.alibaba.com/img/pb/040/331/284/284331040_822.jpg

Answer (score 3):

I managed to connect mine to ADB, even using the included USB cable.

1. Connect you computer to the dongle's OTG port (it's marked on the dongle).
2. Go into settings and enabled ADB debugging.
3. And finally *(here's the trick)* enable the special `Connect to PC` setting.

[image: Enable Connect to PC]

Answer (score 0):

Google for the drivers. Installing the Android SDK will not ensure that your device gets detected.

1. Connect device
2. Install drivers downloaded from internet
3. Disconnect & reconnect
4. ADB !

In all likelihood, this will solve things for you.

Comment: I completely forgot to install drivers for device; unfortunately I couldn't find any searching online.  Otacon's suggestion worked for me though.  Thanks for the suggestion